# create a correlation matrix with a datetime type index dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, data-science

I had 2 different dataset and a merge them with:

```
aaa = pd.merge(time_aragonit, floridaco2, how='inner', on='Time')
```

This is my dataset after the merge:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaTdd.png)

I have datetime type index and when i want to create a correlation matrix, the output look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu1so.png)

Why is the correlation between the values not shown? Where am i doing wrong could you please help me?

i also tried join but got the same result

```
aaa=time_aragonit.join(floridaco2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do not post images, especially for the dataframes. Instead do a print(df) an paste the result in your question, surrounded by ``` and ```. This way, we can use your output to help you with your desired answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have to draw the correlation matrix.

You are instead creating a heatmap of the data-frame itself.

Make the change as shown below:

```
corr_carbonate = aaa.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr_carbonate, cmap="YlGnBu", annot=True)
```

This should give a proper heatmap as you need.